# Visual Studio Code jQuery intellisense in .php file

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to enable jQuery intellisense in Visual Studio Code so that .php pages display the intellisense suggestions in inline javascript scripts?

Comment: If it was in phpstorm https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Comment: JS intellisense is rather broken in VS. I'd suggest another editor if you're working in PHP/JS (and note that I say this as a C# dev who works in VS every day)

Comment: Ok thanks. I had seen this was an issue in old versions so it seems they have not updated it!